# How to open a file in a new tab?

Tags: html

I have a link that should open a PDF in a new tab.

This works as expected on localhost but after I deploy the site the link downloads the pdf instead of opening it.

```
<a download="" target="_blank" href="https://www.my-domain.com.au/foo.pdf">Open PDF</a>
```

How can I ensure the link opens the file in a new tab instead of downloading it?

The actual code is using Nextjs Link, React JSX.

```
<Link href={href}>
  <a
    download={true}
    target="_blank"
    rel={isExternal ? 'noopener' : undefined}
  >
    Open PDF
  </a>
</Link>
```

I am using Chrome

Comment: Try to remove `download` attribute.

Comment: This worked. Please add it as an answer.

Comment: That HTML is thoroughly invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML5 specification [says](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download):

> The `download` attribute, if present, indicates that the author intends the hyperlink to be used for downloading a resource.

So, try to remove it.